Pass a ref to a dynamically loaded ForceGraph2D
I'd like to pass a ref to a dynamically loaded component named ForceGraph2D.
I have used forwardRef to wrap it. But the Chrome still gives a warning: app-index.tsx:25 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
The code is as follows:
src/components/reftest.tsx
"use client";

import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, forwardRef } from 'react';  
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';  

const ForceGraph2D = dynamic(() => import('react-force-graph-2d'), { ssr: false });

const ForwardedForceGraph2D = forwardRef((props, ref) => (  
    <ForceGraph2D {...props} ref={ref} />  
  ));  
ForwardedForceGraph2D.displayName = 'ForceGraphComponent';

const GraphComponent = () => {  
  const [graphRef, setGraphRef] = useState(null);  
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    nodes: [
      { id: 'Node 1' },
      { id: 'Node 2' },
      { id: 'Node 3' }
    ],
    links: [
      { source: 'Node 1', target: 'Node 2' },
      { source: 'Node 2', target: 'Node 3' },
      { source: 'Node 3', target: 'Node 1' }
    ]
  });
 
  const handleRef = useCallback((ref) => {  
    if (ref) {  
      setGraphRef(ref);  
    }  
  }, []);  

   
  useEffect(() => {  
    if (graphRef) {  
      const forceEngine = graphRef.d3Force();  

      
      forceEngine('link').distance(link => link.value * 10);  

       
      forceEngine('charge').strength(-100);  

      
      forceEngine('collide', d3.forceCollide(node => Math.sqrt(node.size)));  

       
      graphRef.d3ReheatSimulation();  
    }  
  }, [graphRef]);  


  const handleNodeClick = useCallback((node) => {  
    if (graphRef) {  
      const forceEngine = graphRef.d3Force();  
      forceEngine('charge').strength(n => n === node ? -1000 : -30);  
      graphRef.d3ReheatSimulation();  
    }  
  }, [graphRef]);  

  return (  
    <ForwardedForceGraph2D  
      ref={handleRef} 
      graphData={data}
      forceEngine="d3"  
      onNodeClick={handleNodeClick}  
   
    />  
  );  
};  

export default GraphComponent;

page.tsx
// pages/index.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from 'antd';
// import Graph from '../components/graphview';
import GraphComponent from '../components/reftest';


const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <Layout >
      <GraphComponent />
    </Layout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

